# IF for a SET variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my code works flawless, but I have one upgrade I need to make, and I can't figure it.
Basically.  I have a price for every year up to 2052 (40 years).  I am staggering these prices to put the starting year and 5 prices in a row for each ID (72 IDs in total). I also have a line number that starts at 550 and increases by 2 each time through the loop.  There is one district (that I know of right now) that needs to increase by 3 each time it goes through the loop. Is there a way to set an IF statement or a CASE statement when you are setting a variable value at the end of a loop?  So when I get to "SET @LINE = @LINE + 2" I need for that to be a condition similar to..

```
CASE
     WHEN DISTRICT = 'ALASKA'
     THEN @LINE = @LINE + 3
     ELSE @LINE = @LINE + 2
END
```

Here is what I am working with right now.

```
DECLARE @IDF INT
DECLARE @FLAG INT       
DECLARE @LINE INT
TRUNCATE TABLE #CODE
SET @IDF = 1
WHILE (@IDF < 73)   
BEGIN   
    SET @FLAG = (SELECT min(YEAR) FROM #TABLE1 WHERE ID = @IDF)
    SET @LINE = 550
    WHILE (@FLAG < 2053)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #CODE(ID,DISTRICT,year,LINE,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
        SELECT ID,
               DISTRICT,
               year,
               (@LINE) AS 'LINE',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG) AS 't1',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+1) AS 't2',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+2) AS 't3',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+3) AS 't4',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+4) AS 't5'
        FROM #TABLE1 WHERE ID = @IDF AND YEAR = @FLAG
    SET @FLAG = @FLAG + 5
    SET @LINE = @LINE + 2
    END
SET @IDF = @IDF + 1
END
```

Comment: His current code is fine he's saying.  He wants help with the next step.

Comment: @jumpingcode no need to nitpick a phrase. Op explained clearly what it is that s/he needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHILE (@IDF < 73)   
BEGIN   
    SET @FLAG = (SELECT min(YEAR) FROM #TABLE1 WHERE ID = @IDF)
    SET @LINE = 550
    WHILE (@FLAG < 2053)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #CODE(ID,DISTRICT,year,LINE,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
        SELECT ID,
               DISTRICT,
               year,
               (@LINE) AS 'LINE',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG) AS 't1',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+1) AS 't2',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+2) AS 't3',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+3) AS 't4',
               (SELECT YEARLY_PRICING FROM #TABLE1 b WHERE b.ID = @IDF AND b.YEAR = @FLAG+4) AS 't5'
        FROM #TABLE1 WHERE ID = @IDF AND YEAR = @FLAG

    SELECT @LINE = CASE 
                        WHEN DISTRICT = 'ALASKA'
                        THEN @LINE + 3
                        ELSE @LINE + 2
                    END
    FROM #CODE
    WHERE LINE = @LINE
    AND [YEAR] = @FLAG

    SET @FLAG = @FLAG + 5
    END
SET @IDF = @IDF + 1
END
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Since this will be outside of my SELECT statement.  How would I have it recognize DISTRICT.

Comment: @user2808684 Ok, you are right. Updated my answer, but this assumes that there is only one row for every combination of `LINE` and `YEAR`. If that's not the case, then you'll need to use `TOP 1` or some logic around this.

Comment: PERFECT! That is exactly what I needed.  It is working as expected.  I used the ID number in "FROM #CODE WHERE ID = @IDF AND YEAR = @FLAG".  Thank you so much for your help.  If I had 15 reputation I would upvote you :)

Comment: @user2808684 Don't worry, no problem. Just in case that you didn't know, if an answer (not necessarily **my** answer) solves you problem, then you can (not necessarily **have to**) mark it as accepted by clicking the check tick that is on the top left of the answer.